# WCF From Class Library - hosting in IIS and wsdl generation

Tags: c#, wcf

Allmost all day today I am trying to research on WCF and one of my aim was to create a WCF service manually (or almost so).

Based on few articles on web on [how to structure WCF application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFProjectStructure.aspx) I have created  contracts  project which contain service interfaces and  implementation project. Both have Runtime.Serialization

I have created app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="FulFillmentServiceBehaviour">
                  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="FulFillmentServiceBehaviour"
                name="Project.Services.Fulfillment">
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/Services" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="" contract="P.Infrastructure.Services.IFulfillment" />
                <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

1) How can I host this service in IIS
 I already created virtual directory pointing to folder containing project Services (url http://localhost:8080/Services)

2) How to create wsdl file  so that I can use SOAPUI to test it

---

I tried adding a file "fulfillment.svc" with  markup

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Project.Services.Fulfillment" CodeBehind="Fulfillment.cs" %>
```

for the purpose of testing but it gave error

**The type Project.Services.Fulfillment', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found.**

Update 1************

just found this on net - may be this will help.   one imp ino is that i will need web.config

http://wncadmb026d.na-idm.na-gad.nec.com/Services/Fulfillment.svc?wsdl

Update 2:*************

SOAP UI is able to  generate SOAP request but gers http 404 as response...

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Developing-a-WCF-Service-Library-and-Hosting-it-as-WCF-Web-Service-Using-VS2K8/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the basic service up  with help from 
http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Developing-a-WCF-Service-Library-and-Hosting-it-as-WCF-Web-Service-Using-VS2K8/

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766(v=VS.90).aspx

I copied service model section from app.congig to web.config

I also had to chaNGE BUILD FOLDER TO /BIN Instead of /bin/debug/

will add more code tomorrow morning

Comment: Changing build folder to bin worked for me (I already had web.config file).

Answer (score 0):

For WSDL page you have the correct attribute:

```
 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
```

And you can access it by adding ?wsdl to the URL, ie http://localhost:8080/Service.svc?wsdl

As for the error, I think the problem is that you are not using the .svc extension:

```
 <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
  Service="Project.Services.Fulfillment" CodeBehind="Fulfillment.svc.cs" %>
```

You are using a .svc file, right?

If you are not using an .svc file one thing to do is use routing, see this link for an example: http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/08/21/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config.aspx

Comment: will service.svc automatically map to service call (Idont have any file called service.svc). I did try using  manually created fulfillment.svc file as stated in my question but my code behind i added as "Fulfillment.cs" and not CodeBehind="Fulfillment.svc.cs". I will updatew you shortly from home if I was able to  access http://localhost:8080/Service.svc?wsdl

Comment: @TheMar How did you create the WCF service? Did you go to File -> New Project and use a WCF service template or are you simply trying to create a service from a bare .cs file? To get a .svc file you should use the templates that are often provided with Visual Studio.

Comment: I created rge svc from text file.